# range, if then, statement to print output based on data

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, if-statement, range

I would like to have the value return a response based on the output of the value within the specified range.

```
import requests
import json
import time
url = 'https://api.gdax.com/products/BTC-USD/trades'
res = requests.get(url)
json_res = json.loads(res.text)


print('val ', json_res[0]['price'])

buy = range(32000, 36000)
sell = range(39000, 50000)

if json_res in buy:
    print('Low')

elif json_res in sell:
    print('Too High')
```

This is an example of the output I'm looking for

```
val 38000.00002545
Too High
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read comment lines

```py
import requests
import json
import time
url = 'https://api.gdax.com/products/BTC-USD/trades'
res = requests.get(url)
json_res = json.loads(res.text)
price = int(float(json_res[0]['price']) // 1) # Convert from str to float to int (to match the range value)

print('val ', price)

buy = range(32000, 39000) # I changed the max range to 39000 as the current BTC price is 38xxx
sell = range(39000, 50000)

if price in buy:
    print('Low')

elif price in sell:
    print('Too High')
```

Pros:

- I still use your `range` syntax
- I warn you about the current BTC price

Answer (score 1):

```
import requests
import json
import time
url = 'https://api.gdax.com/products/BTC-USD/trades'
res = requests.get(url)
json_res = json.loads(res.text)


print('val ', json_res[0]['price'])

if 32000 < float(val)  < 3600:
    print('Low')
elif  39000 < float(val) < 50000:
     print('Too High')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests
import json
import time
url = 'https://api.gdax.com/products/BTC-USD/trades'
res = requests.get(url)
json_res = json.loads(res.text)


print('val ', json_res[0]['price'])

buy = range(32000, 36000)
sell = range(39000, 50000)

if float(json_res[0]['price']) in buy:
    print('Low')

elif float(json_res[0]['price']) in sell:
    print('Too High')
    
else:
    if  float(json_res[0]['price']) <32000:
        print('Lower Than low')
    
    elif float(json_res[0]['price']) >50000:
        print('Higher Than high')
        
    else:
        print('In Between')
```